# Google Cloud disk snapshots default region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google Cloud Disk Snapshots are default located in which regions? Is there region same as Disk region?

Comment: Please publish your question in ServerFault community as this topic is out of scope in StackOverflow. Just to help : snapshots are global resources while disks are regional or zonal resources. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/global-regional-zonal-resources

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you take snapshot in Google cloud, the snapshot data is incremental and the snapshot data is kept in Google cloud object storage and the details of which object storage, where and how is not at all revealed to users.
Because, Google needs to meet some SLAs for those snapshots they would want to disclose details of the snapshot , as to meet SLA s they would be changing and managing snapshots internally that user would be oblivious to

And that's true with other clouds too!!